# iOS 8 Photos framework: Get file name from PHAsset

Tags: ios8, photos, photosframework, phasset

Is there any way to get the file name from PHAsset object in iOS 8, same as like ALAsset's defaultRepresentation provides the file name?

```
// For ALAsset
let defaultRepresentation = self.asset.defaultRepresentation()
let filename = defaultRepresentation.filename()
```

**NOTE:** This can be done in iOS9 using **PHAssetResource** class. But I am looking for iOS8 and documented way of doing this(No undocumented APIs Please).

I did find the same question on SO but did not find the convincing answers, so I thought of asking it separately.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There have a private API called `PHAsset.filename`.

```
let filename = phAsset.value(forKey: "filename") as! String
```

You will get something like "IMG_193.PNG".

Answer (score 1):

There is no documented way to do this on iOS 8.
The only thing you "might" use is the `PHImageFileURLKey` returned in the info Dictionary of the method `requestImageDataForAsset:` of `PHImageManager`. But even this is not fully documented.

Comment: Thanks. I too didn't find any other way so I used PHImageFileURLKey when I request full size image. But when I fetch thumbnail image by requestImageForAsset(_:targetSize:contentMode:options:resultHandler:), there's no such key in info dictionary. Do you have any idea how to get file name when requesting thumbnail image? I need it for setting accessibility hint.